# A reachability problem

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, ds.algorithms, np-hardness, polynomial-time

Let $P$ be a length-preserving (i.e. $|P(x)|=|x|$) 
polynomial-time computable program.

I. 
Given two strings $x$ and $y$, 
we want to decide if $y$ can be obtained by 
repeated applications of $P$ to $x$. 
In other words,
is there a $k$ such that $P^k(x)=y$?

II. Given a string $x$,
find the number strings of length $|x|$ 
which cannot be obtained by repeated applications of $P$ to $x$?

I am looking for [PTAS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial-time_approximation_scheme) algorithms for these problems.

---

The first problem is PSpace-complete, see [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/142064/) on MO.

Comment: I think if your problem is PSPACE-complete (according to the link), then in particular it is [APX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APX)-hard, so there should not be a PTAS. Does that sound right?

Comment: Wouldnt the program P itself count ie does the analysis of the program have any bearing?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out APX hardness  though

Comment: I am guessing that $P$ in the second problem also satisfies the conditions, (length-preserving, polynomial-time computable). Also, do you want to be fixed like the first problem or be part of the input?

Comment: Yes It is the same Program P ; The edit is OK now

Comment: Can you clarify what it means to have a PTAS for problem 1? A PTAS makes sense for optimization or counting problems, but problem 1 is a decision problem.

Comment: PTAS is applicable  only for problem II

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With respect to Problem II, it is coNP-hard (under Karp reductions) to tell if the number of unreachable strings is 0 or at least $1 - 2^{-\text{poly}(|x|)}$ fraction of all strings. I suspect there is a way to boost this and show that the gap problem is PSPACE-hard, maybe by using IP as a robust characterization of PSPACE.

Let $L$ be a coNP-complete language. There exists a polynomial time Turing machine $M$ and a polynomial $p$ such that $x \in L$ if and only if for all $w$, $|w| = p(|x|)$, we have $M(x, w) = 0$.

Construct $P$ to be the following program. It takes $z$ where $|z| = p(|x|) + i$ and maps it to

- itself if $z = (w, 0^{i})$ and $M(x, w) = 1$
- to $z'$, where $z'$ is the successor of $z$ in the lexicographic order, otherwise

Notice that if $x \in L$, then starting from $0^{p(|x|) + i}$ and repeatedly applying $P$ we run through all strings $z$ of size $p(|x|) + i$. Otherwise, there is some $w$ such that $M(x, w) = 1$ and the repeated applications of $P$ reach at most $2^{p(|x|)}$ strings. Taking $i$ to be a large enough polynomial in $|x|$ finishes the proof.

Comment: If I could choose an oracle to help me out (as obviously for even a moderate length string my chances of getting an answer in a lifetime are nil).. which would be the weakest / least complex one; just so I can get some *approximate* value for my function ( number of unreachable strings) in "less" time?.Of course we do not talk of the "reachability Oracle" here, but say if I could use the Boolean SAT oracle. – So now I talk of PTAS with oracle of the least complexity class

Comment: @ARi that sounds something that is better as a new question. and if you want to post it as a new question it might be helpful to specify what oracles you consider acceptable. i do not even see a way to use something like "is string $y$ reachable from string $x$" to answer problem II.